# Exposing a Docker container port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, boot2docker

I have been trying to connect to a docker container via ip, but reamins unsuccessful. When I used "docker inspect container-id" I get this result.

[image: Docker container port]

My virtual box settings are by default:

[image: Virtual box settings]

Can someone help me resolving this issue?

Comment: When you ran docker, did you use the `-p <port number>` parameter to make that port available (or use `expose` in the Dockerfile)?

Comment: No, I din't. Can you tell me how to run the same container with p parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When running docker, you can specify which port(s) you'd like to be accessible to the outside world.  Basic syntax is:

```
docker run -p hostPort:containerPort imageName
```

or just

```
docker run -p hostPort imageName
```

In the first case, externally, `hostPort` will be used, but inside the container: `containerPort` will be used.  In the second instance, you'd just be using that port both inside and outside your container.

You can also create an image with ports exposed by using the [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) command in a Dockerfile.

Comment: I commit the container, stopped it, and then run the latest image by using docker run -p 2375 imageName, but still no result...

Comment: Does `docker inspect new_container_id` show the same thing?

Comment: Here you are specifying the image name,  what if we have a container with modification and data in the database, and we want to expose a certain port on that container.

Comment: @Bionix1441:  You can't easily do that, but there are some workarounds.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container/42071577#42071577) is one

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform port forwarding or just simply expose port.

#### Port Forwarding:

docker run -p 2022:22 -p 2375:2375

#### Expose Port:

docker run -p 22 -p 2375

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ran these commands but nothing happened.

Comment: Image name is missing in the command