# Docker: Expose a range of ports

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to expose a range of ports while starting Docker container?

a command like so would be very helpful:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8000-9000:8000-9000
```

Comment: possible duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container

Comment: No it wasn't a duplicated of the mentioned question. There is a newer question very similar that has already been resolved. In case anybody lands here, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717464/docker-expose-all-ports-or-range-of-ports-from-7000-to-8000

Answer (score 9):

Here is a similar question that caters your requirement as well.
[Docker expose all ports or range of ports from 7000 to 8000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717464/docker-expose-all-ports-or-range-of-ports-from-7000-to-8000)

To summarize here, Yes it is possible since Docker version 1.5. You can expose port range when executing `docker run` command like this:

```
docker run -p 192.168.0.10:8000-9000:8000-9000
```

or

```
docker run -p 8000-9000:8000-9000
```

I have verified that its working fine on my machine using Docker version 1.6.

Comment: Just one caveat, if you try to expose more than 1000 ports one some systems it will be blocked. The work-around is to use ``--net host`` which exposes docker to the host network port controller.