# Docker expose all ports or range of ports from 7000 to 8000

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Can I specify a port range in a Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 7000-8000
```

and when running the container bind all these exposed ports to the same ports on the host machine?

```
docker run -p 7000-8000:7000-8000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: Expose a range of ports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022656/docker-expose-a-range-of-ports)

Answer (score 195):

Since Docker 1.5 you can now **expose** a range of ports to other linked containers using:

The Dockerfile [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) command:

`EXPOSE 7000-8000`

or The Docker [run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command:

`docker run --expose=7000-8000`

Or instead you can **publish** a range of ports to the host machine via Docker [run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command:

`docker run -p 7000-8000:7000-8000`

Comment: Check output of  "iptables -L -n" on the host machine and you will see hundreds of lines each for single port mapping. If you give 5000-50000 , then practically you have to wait for a long time.Is this the supposed behaviour?

Comment: @ᐅdevrimbaris There is also a [docker process being launched per port](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37770567/1318694). I believe this is what takes up most of the work time.

Comment: the docs talk about the `--publish-all , -P` flag which "Publish all exposed ports to random ports". http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: besides what @ᐅdevrimbaris has warned about the iptables rules,  when a range is large enough, docker eats up all RAM and fails, see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11185, and the issue is still open.