# Why does Docker run so many processes to map ports though to my application?

Tags: docker

I have an application that runs in a container that requires a range of ports to be mapped to it.

```
docker run -p 2000-3000:2000-3000 myapp
```

When I run this docker command my development vm grinds to a halt.

Then looking at the processes, there is a `docker-proxy` running for every port

```
$ ps -ef 
...
root     19796  7835  0 03:31 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 4000 -container-ip 172.17.0.4 -container-port 3000
root     19804  7835  0 03:31 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 3999 -container-ip 172.17.0.4 -container-port 2999
root     19812  7835  0 03:31 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 3998 -container-ip 172.17.0.4 -container-port 2998
...

$ ps -ef | grep -c docker-proxy
1003
```

They are all children of the docker daemon

```
root@default-docker:~# pstree -p
init(1)-+-VBoxService(1251)
        |-acpid(1277)
        |-crond(1235)
        |-docker(7835)-+-docker-containe(7841)-+-docker-containe(8031)---gitlab-ci-multi(8048)
        |              |                       |-docker-containe(9678)---mysqld(9693)
        |              |                       `-docker-containe(20577)---registry(20591)
        |              |-exe(19796)
        |              |-exe(19804)
        |              |-exe(19812)
```

Each process uses a chunk of private memory (`Pss` in `/proc/$pid/smaps`)

```
$ for pid in $(pgrep exe); do printf "pid:%5s mem:%5s\n" $pid $(awk '/^Pss:/{t=t+$2}END{print t}' /proc/$pid/smaps); done
...
pid:28534 mem: 4011
pid:28543 mem: 3817
pid:28552 mem: 4001
```

There are also DNAT rules in place for each port, which is how I would have expected this to be done on a Linux host with private networks.

```
root@default-docker:~# iptables -t nat -vnL DOCKER
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
...
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4000 to:172.17.0.4:3000
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3999 to:172.17.0.4:2999
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3998 to:172.17.0.4:2998
...
```

Why is Docker launching a process per port?
Why does each process need 4-6MB of memory?
Why is Docker using a user space process at all?

Comment: BTW, http://windsock.io/tag/docker-proxy/ covers why docker-proxy exists.

Comment: ...and links to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11185, re: the associated memory usage.

Comment: Which release of Docker are you running?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the links, I've been meaning to look at this for a while.  v1.11.1

Comment: Okay -- 1.7 introduced the ability to disable the userland proxy functionality, so you should have that available.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Going by that `docker-proxy` page, it appears to exist to support an OS and kernel that isn't supported by docker any more!

Comment: Until Docker changes their model for host publishing, assuming that's even possible with their design, I'd change how this container is networked. Don't publish any ports on the host. Put it on a bridged network you define with a known IP and make sure the iptables rules allow outside traffic that you want to route directly to the container ip.

Comment: @BMitch we do something similar, by mapping a real world interface to these containers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Why is Docker using a user space process at all?

Nigel Brown has written a detailed article on [The docker-proxy](http://windsock.io/tag/docker-proxy/) which explains the how and why.

> The `docker-proxy`, then, is a 'catch all' method for allowing container
>   port forwarding to the Docker host. However, it's generally considered
>   that the `docker-proxy` is an inelegant solution to the problems
>   highlighted above, and when a large range of container ports are
>   exposed, it consumes considerable memory. An attempt was previously
>   made to remove the dependency for the `docker-proxy`, but this fell foul
>   of the limitations of the aged kernel in RHEL 6.x and CentOS 6.x,
>   which the Docker project feels duty bound to support. Hence, the
>   `docker-proxy` remains a major constituent part of the Docker experience
>   in all Docker versions up to the current version 1.5. As I write,
>   version 1.6 is due for imminent release, and there have been moves to
>   remove the automatic requirement for the `docker-proxy`, which I'll
>   cover in another article.

Docker now includes a daemon run time option to [disable the userland proxy with `--userland-proxy=false`](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14856). This was introduced in v1.7.

There seems to be a [few](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5618) edge case [bugs](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22741) that [exist](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21860) when disabling the userland proxy. There are also [IPV6 issues](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/1099)

There is an open GitHub issue for disabling the [userland proxy by default](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14856) (RHEL6 is no longer supported by Docker).

### Why is Docker launching a process per port?

There doesn't appear to be a reason for this other than it was implemented this way. A single process should be capable of handling all of the port mappings for a container

### Why does each process need 4-6MB of memory?

<strike>The [proxy implementation](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/3d13fddd2bc4d679f0eaa68b0be877e5a816ad53/vendor/src/github.com/docker/libnetwork/portmapper/proxy.go) and [package](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/befada2ca7064997c3b1f3d65999ffa323dcba73/pkg/proxy/tcp_proxy.go) looks clean and uses in built Go functionality so this might just be Go's initial garbage collection limits that allow it to grow to ~ 5MB.</strike>

**EDIT**: Memory usage has [been improved in Docker 1.12](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/23312). There is still a process per port but each process now only uses ~ 750k of private memory space.