# How to get and set random service port as env var inside docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

Here an example of a docker-compose.yml :

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: ghost:latest
    ports:
      - 0:2368
    environment:
      url: http://ghost.localhost:30001
```

I would like to get service random port and set inside `url` env variable like this:

`url: "http://ghost.localhost:{{.Service.Port}}"`

The final goal it's to deploy multiple stacks without manually set port.

`docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml ghost1`
`docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml ghost2`
`docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml ghost3`

It's possible ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible now. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3778) but it is still open (it is more than 4 years old).

Comment: the feature request is for getting the port inside container. however the question is asking for a variable substitution solution which is probably much easier to safely implement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select a port range (I would recommend using a higher range, like 9000-9100), but keep in mind that a process is being launched for every open port: [Why does Docker run so many processes to map ports though to my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770567/why-does-docker-run-so-many-processes-to-map-ports-though-to-my-application) So the performance is likely going to be less than ideal.

You might want to look into using docker "host networking" or some other non-default networking setup.

Answer (score 0):

Use .env file to define dynamic values in docker-compse.yml. Be it port or any other value.

Sample docker-compose:

```
testcore.web:
       image: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/testcore:latest
       volumes: 
            - c:/logs:c:/logs
       ports:
            - ${TEST_CORE_PORT}:80
       environment:
            - CONSUL_URL=http://${CONSUL_IP}:8500 
            - HOST=${HOST_ADDRESS}:${TEST_CORE_PORT}
```

Inside .env file you can define the value of these variables:

```
CONSUL_IP=172.31.28.151
HOST_ADDRESS=172.31.16.221
TEST_CORE_PORT=10002
```