# How to expose port ranges (like "3000-4000:3000-4000") in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: range, port, docker-compose

How to expose port ranges (like "3000-4000:3000-4000") in docker-compose.yml file

ports:
   - "3000-4000:3000-4000"

it not working. Please help me to resolve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker expose all ports or range of ports from 7000 to 8000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717464/docker-expose-all-ports-or-range-of-ports-from-7000-to-8000)

Comment: How is it "not working". Please provide the error you are getting.

Comment: in docker-compose syntax is different than command line, user is trying to find that, It is not duplicate because that threat is about command line

Comment: This question related to port publishing, not exposing ports at all. The top answer also relates to port publishing, not port exposing. These are well defined terms in docker and are being misused here. If the question is about publishing please rephrase.

Answer (score 55):

There is possibly mistake in the syntax you are using. The ports are defined in the next line and after leaving some space. It should work and as specified in the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports). See example below:

```
ports:
 - "3000"
 - "3000-3005"
 - "8000:8000"
 - "9090-9091:8080-8081"
 - "49100:22"
 - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
 - "127.0.0.1:5000-5010:5000-5010"
 - "6060:6060/udp"
```