# Docker network with open ports

Tags: docker

Is it possible to make all ports opened in Docker? I suppose that I can create `network` and set it up somehow, but I can't find how (while I know that it's possible).

To be precise I mean that i want to have in `docker-compose.yml`

```
   networks:
      - my_network
```

instead of

```
   ports:
      - 12000:12000

   networks:
      - my_network
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker expose all ports or range of ports from 7000 to 8000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717464/docker-expose-all-ports-or-range-of-ports-from-7000-to-8000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use host network that way all ports will be open.

Use network_mode in the yaml file

```
network_mode: "host"
```

Comment: Ah, so it's possible if containers have no access from outside