# Is posible define range of port to use in expose `-P` in docker?

Tags: docker

Is posible something to limit the range of ports to expose with `-P` parameter, like as:

`docker daemon --range-ports=2000-2099...`

`docker run -P...` <- ports used between 2000 and 2099

or

`docker daemon...`

`docker run -P --range-ports=2000-2099...` <- ports used between 2000 and 2099`

Comment: Yes, it's right there in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports.

Comment: That's a duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717464/docker-expose-all-ports-or-range-of-ports-from-7000-to-8000 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022656/docker-expose-a-range-of-ports

Comment: @Auzias I'm talking about `-P` parameter with uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

you can give range of ports to be mapped;

```
docker run -d -p 8000-9000:5000 training/webapp python app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI I have created follow issue:
[docker#20091](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20091)

The answer was:
`docker run .... -p 2000-2099:22 -p 2000-2099:23 -p 2000-2099:24 ....`

Thank you for your answer