# Docker-compose open all ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm am deploying an app inside a docker container that randomly assigns ports when it starts.
The problem is I want to use `docker-compose` but is there a way to expose all ports for the service using docker-compose? Without docker-compose, I would use `docker run ... -P`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: Expose a range of ports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022656/docker-expose-a-range-of-ports)

Comment: @mttdbrd - nope, read the question!

Comment: Sorry. What version of Docker Compose are you using? This was supposed to be fixed in 1.6.0: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2629. You would basically use a range in a string: - "8200-8219"

Comment: I do not thing that you would be able to expose ALL ports (1-65535). That would left no ports for host. Probably you need some ports for SSH, docker demon, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd recommend using port ranges i.e

`ports:
 - "1-65535:1-65535"`

You will probably need to tinker with this range according to your app specifications so that you won't accidentally expose something that's already in use by the host (such as SSH).

Answer (score 1):

docker-compose version 1.25.0

---

Use it like following

---

ports: [22, 23]

It needs to be array of port numbers.