# how do I expose an http traffic of a docker container to the outside world

Tags: docker

I have a docker container, which serves some http traffic on  172.17.0.87:9000, which is internal to that specific container.
How do I expose this traffic to the outside world, so I could hit http://example.com:9000 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exposing a port on a live Docker container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Seth: docker run -i -t me/mycontainer -p 9000:9000 will expose the traffic