# Is it possible to open new ports on the fly in Kube pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run a software in side Kubernetes that open more pods at runtime based on various operations. Is it possible to open more ports on the fly in a Kubernetes pod? It does not seem to be possible at the Docker level ([Exposing a port on a live Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container)) which means Kubernetes can't do it either (I guess ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Pod in Kubernetes gets its own IP address. So a container (application) in a Pod can use any port as long as that port is not used by any other container within the same Pod.

Now if you want to expose those dynamic ports, it will require additional configuration though. Ports are exposed using Services, and service configuration has to be updated to expose those dynamic ports.