# How to dynamically modify the startup parameters of a running container?

Tags: docker

Imaging this scenario, I've started an tomcat container days ago by executing this command:

```
  docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 --name foo tomcat:7.0
```

It worked fine and I've made some changes inside this `foo` container like installing necessary dependencies and editor.

But today I found besides port 8080, I need to expose another port `8005` of this container. So my question is how dynamically change this container's startup parameters so that all my changes made to this `foo` container will be kept?

Currently I only came up with one idea:

```
docker commit foo bar:latest
docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 -p 8005:8005 --name bar bar:latest
```

Is there an better solution?

Comment: There are some ideas in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container

Comment: Yeah, it seems so far there's no better solution than `commit` the container and then rerun form the new image. thanks for your link, very helpful.