# Assign port to container

Tags: docker, port, containers

in My Container ID `634eb4c5d6ee`, This is my Ports : `docker port 634eb4c5d6ee
222/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:222
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
8443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:443`

i want Change `8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80` to `8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:90`

**how can i do it on Docker ?**

and ***Published*** port `80` to another Container ID `8e8caeca7a87`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [issue 3285](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3285), this is not yet possible (to modify port mapping on a running container).

Even the 1.10+ [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) command does not yet update ports.
This is followed by [issue 21282](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21282).

You have other options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19897743/6309), like using iptables, or committing the live container, and relaunching it.

Comment: how can i published port to container ?  `docker port 80 ContainerID` not work

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi by relaunching it with the correct port mapping (once the first once has been also relaunched with a *different* port mapping)

Comment: im run `docker run -p 80:80 kali2`    and `docker ps -a` i see it Created but ports is empty  `6dfcd05c39ea        kali2                      "/bin/bash"              About a minute ago   Exited (0) 55 seconds ago  `  now i start container `docker start 6dfcd05c39ea`   seems not start my container

Comment: @MehranGoudarzi That is a completely different question. Please ask a new one, with your OS and docker version (and a link to this one)