# Docker: Exposing Port on Running Container

Tags: docker, containers, iptables

I'm trying to `expose` a port in a running Docker Container. I've tried to use the `exec` command and `IPTables`, but they are not working. Any ideas on exposing the running container or saving the running container to keep the same configurations?

Comment: It's explained here might be helpful,. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container