# Docker containers communication via http

Tags: spring, docker

I have two Spring web services which should communicate via http. Both of them are running on my machine in dcoker containers over openjdk:8-jre-alpine. Here is the POST query which fails with "Connection refused" :

```
public String createPost(int playerCount) {
    String uri = URI + "/create";
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
            .queryParam("playerCount", playerCount);
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.exchange(
            builder.build().encode().toUri(),
            HttpMethod.POST,
            entity,
            String.class);
    logger.info("Create request");
    return response.getBody();
}
```

URI is `http://localhost:8090/game`
Here is corresponding controller of other service:

```
@RequestMapping(
        path = "create",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<Long> create(@RequestParam("playerCount") int playerCount) {
    long gameId = gameService.create(playerCount);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(gameId, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I'm simply running both containers with `run -p 8080:8080` and '8090:8090' . And as I said previously getting "Connection refused" How to set up communication properly?
**NOTE:** it works fine if I run it with Intellij.

Comment: have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default Docker bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network) does not provide direct communication between containers without "links". Links have been deprecated and it's recommended to use a [user defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks).

Create a [user defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks) for the containers and access each service via the name of the container

```
docker network create spring
docker run --detach --network=spring --name first -p 8080:8080 busybox \
  nc -llp 8080 0.0.0.0 -e echo first
docker run --detach --network=spring --name second -p 8090:8090 busybox \
  nc -llp 8090 0.0.0.0 -e echo second
```

Then you can then ping the other container or connect to a network service

```
# First to second
docker exec first ping second
docker exec first nc second 8090

# Second to first
docker exec second ping first
docker exec second nc first 8080
```

The same definition can also be done with [Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) which configures the network and service names for you based on yaml config.

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  first:
    image: first
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  second:
    image: second
      - '8090:8090'
```

Comment: I've seen this, but still, what URL should I use to execute http query inside?