# How can I expose a docker port when running a container?

Tags: docker, port, docker-run

I'm using the following Docker version

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

I'm building my image using the following command

```
docker build -f my.Dockerfile .
```

which tells me

```
Successfully built 367dc883875e
```

How do I run the above image and expose port 3000?  I tried this

```
docker run -p localhost:3000:3000 367dc883875e
docker: invalid publish opts format (should be name=value but got 'localhost:3000:3000').
See 'docker run --help'.
```

but get the error you see above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exposing a port on a live Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container)

Comment: Why did you include `localhost`? Look at the examples in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/.

Comment: From the man page: `-p, --publish ip:[hostPort]:containerPort | [hostPort:]containerPort`. It works if you specify an IP (127.0.0.1), but not with a hostname.