# Forward a remote Docker container's port onto localhost

Tags: docker, unix, networking, ssh, containers

I have containers running in docker-compose networks on a remote VPS. I would like to be able to access a database running in one of these containers from my localhost.

Eg, if the containers `app` and `db` are in a container network on the VPS, I want to access `db:5432` from *my machine's* `localhost:5432`. Kubernetes' CLI allows this with `kubectl port-forward <service-name> 5432:5432`.

Are there any existing solutions to achieve this effect within existing unix commands and Docker's API? My searching around the Internet hasn't yielded any CLI to do this.

Cheers.

---

**Edit:** I have accepted Ali Tou's answer, however, it would be great to see a solution which does not require restarting a container to re-configure its ports to expose them onto the host.

**Edit 2:** I found a clever method for forwarding traffic in the Docker network using socat in a tangentially-related post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42071577/12406113. This is, however, publicly exposing the port instead of creating a tunnel, such as in the SSH solution.

Comment: What is the point of forwarding to your localhost?

Comment: @AliTou - In my case it would be to work on the same DB as a partner during development. It's also useful for debugging a DB with your preferred client and troubleshooting in general.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the target machine?

Comment: you need to map your local port to the port of your VPS, I think below tutorial is useful also you can always do port mapping with SSH as @AliTou pointed https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/configure-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu/

Comment: That's not a programming question, possibly better suited to superuser.com.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have SSH access to the target machine where the container is running, you can achieve this in two steps:

1. Expose container port into your VPS port, binding to its loopback IP for security:

```yaml
ports:
  - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
```

2. Use SSH port-forwarding to access port 5432 of that container:

```sh
ssh -f -N -L 127.0.0.1:5432:127.0.0.1:5432 <VPS_IP>
```

The above command might seem confusing, but it's requesting SSH to listen on `127.0.0.1:5432` on your client system (first ip:port pair) and port forward its connections through an ssh tunnel to `127.0.0.1:5432` (second ip:port pair) of the remote system (demonstrated with `<VPS_IP>`). See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156813/343873) for more info.

Note that this ssh connection is persistent until your network remains connected. If you want to close this connection, do a `ps aux | grep ssh` to find PID of ssh-forwarding process, then use `sudo kill -9 $PID` to kill it.

P.S. However, this is not different with the case you connect directly to `VPS_IP:5432` if you don't have security concerns.

Comment: This is just the solution I was looking for, thank you! I was unaware that you could bind the IP for a port internally. I thought it was going to be much more complicated, for security reasons. Absolute beauty.

Comment: pretty neat! what about a service? i can't bind service to 127.0.0.1 i get this error `invalid argument "127.0.0.1:15672:15672" for "--publish-add" flag: hostip is not supported`

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi You should post it as another question or look for it in their GitHub issues. I found an old issue describing your problem here, however it's unanswered: https://github.com/docker-archive/classicswarm/issues/2478

Answer (score -1):

You can just use ports section where you can specify host port and container port to forward request https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, but this is not what I was asking. If you read the example, see that I am looking to access the container's port from an entirely different machine to the host of the container network.

Comment: You can use the remote system's host name and the published port number to access the service.