# Should I include localhost when forwarding ports in Docker?

Tags: docker

Whenever I want to forward ports in a Docker container, I used a simple `-p 8080:8080` command.

Now, I read in a couple of places ([here](https://github.com/alpine-docker/socat#example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64630608/5197270)), that this is possibly insecure, and that I should include the localhost loopback, like this: `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080`.

Could someone shed more light on this?
When should this be done and what is the actual security impact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify an ip address when publishing ports, the published ports are available on all interfaces. That is, if you run `docker run -p 8080:8080 ...`, then other systems on your network can access the service on port 8080 on your machine (and if your machine has a publicly routable address, then systems elsewhere in the world can access the service as well). (Of course, you may have host- or network- level firewall rules that prevent this access in any case.)

When you specify an ip address in the port publishing specification, like `127.0.0.1:8080:8080`, then the listening ports are bound explicitly to that interface.

If your listening ports are bound only to the loopback interface, `127.0.0.1`, then only clients on your local machine will be able to connect -- from the perspective of devices elsewhere on the network, those ports aren't available.

Which configuration makes sense depends (a) on what you want to do (maybe you *want* to expose a service that will be accessible to systems other than your local machine), (b) what your local network looks like, and (c) your level of risk aversion.

Comment: Got it. My motivation for this issue came from the fact that I got hacked by a cryptominer argon2, multiple times, despite recreating the VM from scratch. I managed to honeypot it and determine that it got in via a docker container running `socat`, which included port forwarding of the unix docker socket. The issue disappeared when I included `localhost` in the port mapping.