# ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 remote_server - "Adddress already in use" with docker server on remote instance

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm trying to port forward the Remote Instance which has a docker server running on port 8080.

A clip of the docker-compose file is shown here:

```
airflow-webserver:
  <<: *airflow-common
  command: webserver
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  ...
```

When I try `ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 remote_server`
I get the following:

```
bind [127.0.0.1]:8080: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080
Could not request local forwarding.
```

I would like to view the UI of the server from my local machine. I can modify the docker-compose file if need be.

I've tried the method shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64629210/forward-a-remote-docker-containers-port-onto-localhost#answer-64630608) which did not work.

I've also tried `ssh -L 8085:127.0.0.1:8080 remote_server`

This did not work either. The browser turned up connection timed out on port 8085.