# Where are docker images and containers stored when we use it with Windows?

Tags: windows, image, docker, containers

NOTE: Am super new to both Windows and Docker

The tutorial I've been using says that they are under `/var/lib/docker/containers` if we're using Linux, but I can't seem to find that on my Windows machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container/63455911#63455911

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I assign a port mapping to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enter docker-machine with

```
docker-machine ssh
```

there you should find your containers.

```
sudo ls /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Comment: Note that boot2docker is now deprecated. In new versions of docker, you can do the same but with `docker-machine ssh` instead.

Comment: After entering the given commands, I got some encrypted texts. How do I know which are the images ?

Comment: @Shreyas Those long strings are actually names of container config directories.

Answer (score 22):

Things might have changed with Windows 10 Anniversary Update. I installed Docker from source here (https://master.dockerproject.org/windows/amd64/docker-1.13.0-dev.zip) as described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10

Docker puts all of the images in this folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter
```

and all containers in this folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\docker\containers
```

An easy way to check is to execute this:

```
docker info
```

It should tell you where your files are stored:

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 10
Server Version: 1.13.0-dev
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
...
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
...
```

Comment: @Johny.  This location is empty for me.

Comment: @NeerajChand What do you see if you run `docker info`?

Comment: This applies to windows containers only

Answer (score 7):

After review some post on Stackoverflow and Google. I found this directory :

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
```

Here you can fin the configuration with the Virtual Machines

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines
```

Another important thing is the images are virtualized by the Hyper-V, so the info should be stored here.

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Update 2020 for WSL2

If you're using this with WSL2, docker images will be maintained inside of your [wsl drive](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/) available at **`\\wsl$\`** per this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4176):

- **Windows**: `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes`
- **Linux**: `sudo ls /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/volumes`

Answer (score 1):

Docker installed on windows with docker toolbox(using virtual box in place of hyper-v) 
one VM is created on at
`C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.docker\machine\machines` with name `default` so you can find all VM files in default folder.

you can connect this vm using

`docker-machine ssh`

and you can find pulled images and container under this path (you may need to use sudo sometimes)

> /var/lib/docker

Answer (score 0):

I use WSL 2 and my images downloaded to next location:
c:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data
Hope it helps.