# Where are containers located in the host's file system?

Tags: docker, containers, windows-server-2016

I'm currently experimenting with Docker containers on Windows Server. I've created a number of containers, and I want to see where they are actually saved on the host's file system (like a .vhd file for Hyper-V). Is there a default location I can look, or a way to find that out using Docker CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other answers suggest the data might be stored in:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx
```

or since the Windows 10 Anniversary Update:

```
C:\ProgramData\docker\containers
```

You can find out by entering:

```
docker info
```

Credit to / More info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419398/331637
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39971954/331637

Comment: In case the user is using Hyper-v, and not VirtualBox - this answer is correct. My machine back home is using Virtualbox since Hyper-V is not included in Home editions of windows so take it into account