# How to connect localhost:5500/em after the first installation?

Tags: localhost, oracle12c, oracle-xe

I have installed Oracle 12c client in my system and I was able to go to link https://localhost:5500/em at installation.When I restart the system I am unable to go to the link.But my sqlplus works fine.I checked some [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/345282) in this link they asked to verify a status using **emctl status dbconsole**.When I type the command it shows emctl is not recognized.
Can anyone help me in this issue of connecting the localhost and emctl? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check if enterprise manager is listening

```
select dbms_xdb_config.gethttpsport () from dual;
select dbms_xdb_config.gethttspsport () from dual;
```

To start it use this:

```
exec dbms_xdb_config.sethttpsport (5500);
```

Comment: SQL> exec dbms_xdb_config.sethttpsport(5500)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.      Yet i cant access login page

Comment: First of all: verify that the listener is started by executing the lsnrctl status command. You should find line regarding your EM Express tcp port. Log in to SQL*Plus as the SYSDBA user and verify that the DISPATCHERS parameter in the initialization parameter file includes the PROTOCOL=TCP attribute - show parameters dispatchers. Have you checked it by query: select dbms_xdb_config.gethttspsport () from dual ? It may be network problem like tcp port blocked by firewall. Can you establish connection to that port using telnet like: telnet hostname 5500?

Comment: I checked using that query.My port num is 5501.I dont know how to verify DISPATCHERS as am a beginner.Could you tell me the steps please?All the proxy settings are done.I am using windows defender.I was able to see that page only at the time of installation.

Comment: should I reinstall again :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same issue after installing oracle 12R2 in my local machine running on Windows 7. then i tried several steps and it didn't work for me. So i have removed the oracle and re-installed it and now its working as expected

to remove the Oracle successfully follow the below steps

1. first you need to remove the environment variable entry for the oracle (My computer > properties > Advanced System Settings> Advance > Environment Variable) in the system variable section find the entry called 'path' and then remove only the oracle home entry.
2. Then go to registry edit > HKEY_LOCL_MACHINE >Software and remove the folder called 'oracle'
3. Then Again go to Registry edit >  HKEY_LOCL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CURRENT CONTROL SET >  SERVICES and remove all the folders having name 'oracle' in my case i had 5/6 folders  you need to delete one by one.
4. then restart the machine  -  this will stop all the oracle services
5. then delete your oracle home if it says that you cant delete it try refreshing the system
6. after that you need to delete the folder called 'oracle' inside the program file folder
7. then delete the folder entry from start menu as well (you can find the folder path from the properties of the start menu folder )
8. as the final step go to my computer >  Manage > Local user groups and  remove the oracle user  (if you use the default windows user as oracle user then you need to go to properties of that user and remove the all entries for oracle user from "member of tab")
9. empty the recycle bin

10.. finally restart the machine  (not required but to clear all the things) and reinstall the new oracle home  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good page for instructions on how to install and verify your Oracle setup. The part about verifying your installation might be of interest here.

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html

If ur running windows open services.msc and make sure the oracle services are running, all of em!

Answer (score 0):

In my case after running official Oracle XE 18 docker image on WSL2 there was no published ports at all.

To enable OEM console it helped to [manually add 1521, 5500, 8080 ports to the docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container/49371983#49371983) at first and then to consecutively execute

```
exec dbms_xdb_config.sethttpsport (0);
```

and then

```
exec dbms_xdb_config.sethttpsport (5500);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below website is incorrect. Per the [Oracle XE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinl/using-enterprise-manager-express.html#GUID-35C7E577-5FCF-4C5E-B7E7-91FA6DFB59C5), you need to allow anything other than localhost to view the EM. In sqlplus:

`EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);`

That said, I have been unable to access the EM after running the Oracle XE docker image built from https://github.com/gvenzl/oci-oracle-xe (https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe) - I raised the issue at https://github.com/gvenzl/oci-oracle-xe/issues/166

<s>You mentioned that `emctl` is not available so it sounds like you might have installed Oracle XE.</s>

If you installed Oracle XE (Express Edition), Enterprise Manager is not available

See http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_se_ee.htm