# Docker commit is not saving the last state

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to open a publish a new port.
I want to create an image and then creating a new container from that image.
I was following this solution:
[How do I assign a port mapping to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26622041/2647868)

When I'm using docker commit an then docker run the new container does not contain the filesystem changes I've done.

What may cause such a behavior?

Comment: Docker commit does not save the volume state. Do you have any volume?

Comment: How can I tell?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/ricardobranco777/docker-volumes.sh) from [RicardoBranco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7511971/ricardo-branco) may help