# Modifying port binding from docker-compose.yml without recreating container

Tags: docker, ports

I've created a container from `ubuntu:latest` image. For this I've created this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  test_port:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    container_name: test_port
    tty: true
    privileged: true
```

Now I enter into container with `docker exec -it <test_port_id> bash` and I do some work into. Suddenly I realize that I need bind ports with host port, so I stop the container and I add the `port` section to my `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  test_port:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    container_name: test_port
    tty: true
    privileged: true
    ports:
        - "12345:12345"
```

If now I run `docker-compose up` again, Docker recreates container `test_port`, giving it a new ID, this is, Docker create a new container and I lose all my work done in `test_port`.

**My question is:** is there any way to bind ports (or make changes in general) in existing container from `docker-compose.yml` without recreating container but changes taking effect?

**EDIT**: Creating an image from container is not an option. Original problem has `volume` section for time synchronization (`npt`) and if I construct a new container from this image it throws an error because of this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assign a port mapping to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container)

Comment: Not exactly. Creating an image from a container is not possible because in the original problem I have `volumes`. This procedure generates errors, so this is not an option.

Comment: The question is still a duplicate. There are other answers below the top one. I don't think you are going to get any answers besides what is there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that a container can be created or deleted at any times. So if you have to modify files in your container, you have to inject them during the build (dockerfile) or with a volume. This is how you can persist your changes.