# How do I open up a new port in an old docker container running in Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker, window

How do I open up a new port in a docker container running in Docker for Windows?
The container is already created with a different list of exposed ports, I want to keep the old ports and add a new port.

There is already a question about this for Linux, here: [How do I assign a port mapping to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container#26622041)

But for Docker for Windows the configuration files are different (or missing) so that answer does not apply here.

Docker Version 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513)

Comment: I’m almost positive that the exact same answers in the question you linked apply to both Windows and Linux.  Fundamentally you have to delete the container and `docker run` a new one.  (And go with the later answer recommending making it easy to `docker rm` containers without losing data; IMHO `docker commit` isn’t a good habit to be in.)

Comment: @DavidMaze: I am not interested in that solution. I want to keep my old container, and edit its ports, like we do in Linux in this file: /var/lib/docker/containers/[hash_of_the_container]/hostconfig.json. But apparently that file is not present in Windows (see holdfenytolvaj' answer).

Comment: hostconfig.json filepath is:
"\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wslg\distro\data\docker\containers\cd89e5af1065fa1d8b146b764b28d5bce252f562a1308bbbc0b51fa6f799a6bf\hostconfig.json"

where cd89e5af1065fa1d8b146b764b28d5bce252f562a1308bbbc0b51fa6f799a6bf is container ID (shown below container name in docker desktop app).

However, I don't know how to set write rights...