# Accessing config.v2.json file of a docker container (Windows 10 docker desktop)

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

Hello I need to change the ports of a running container (I want to update current container, not creating a new one).

Apparently one way to achieve this is by changing the config.v2.json file for the container in question.

But I am running Docker on a Windows 10 machine, and I cannot find where that file is (on Linux it is on `/var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/config.v2.json` and on Windows it used to be on `c:\Programdata\Docker\Containers\[container-id]\config.v2.json` but this is not the case anymore).

Anyone knows where to access that file nowadays?
Or maybe there is a better approach to change config params of an existing container?
Thanks!

Comment: The correct approach is to delete and recreate the container.  You should not be manually editing files in `/var/lib/docker` at all.  It’s not obvious to me that changing that JSON file would actually result in any behavior change in Docker.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container/63455911#63455911

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I assign a port mapping to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container)

Comment: I find all the files under `\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\` but it's always rebuilt even I modified the content.

Answer (score 3):

I found mine here (19.03.13-beta2)

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\
```

For previous versions, it may be here

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data\data\docker
```

To access from within WSL `\\wsl$` is `/mnt/wsl`

Comment: Funny, I can find the director `community` in `version-pack-data` in window explorer, but I cannot find any director within in WSL