# localhost:3000 JavaScript Problem in de app.get

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Js.
I have a problem in the code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("The Express is running");
});

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('Ok');
});
```

running node app.js i have the answer "Ok".But, running in the browser(localhost:3000)  i get : "The connection was refused".
necessary info: I'm use a container docker, which I use the ubuntu. Can this cause a problem?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I assign a port mapping to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container)

Comment: @Krzystof according to: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container) I have compromised my container for a new container, I did "docker run -p 3000: 3000 -td new", but the problem still continues. I've run in this new container and nothing.