# where is hostconfig.json (Docker desktop + WSL2 environment)

Tags: docker, wsl-2

As I know, docker doesn't support any command that change port mapping after make container.
But this answer said that by changing the hostconfig.json file, I can change port mapping.

[How do I assign a port mapping to an existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container)
I'm using docker desktop in windows + WSL2.So path of hostconfig.json is different with other answers.
Where is hostconfig.json?
In my case, (\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\mnt\wsl\docker-desktop-data\data, /var/lib/docker(in wsl)) directories are not exist.

Comment: Deleting and recreating the container should be pretty routine, and it's better practice than trying to modify Docker internals.

Comment: @DavidMaze Then you mean make container as image and using that image, make new container when I need new ports? Could you explain why it is better? Modify docker internal config may have a problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Where it can be accessed

`hostconfig.json` for a container can be found in WSL2 using Windows Explorer at the hidden network path `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\{containerid}\hostconfig.json`

[Windows Explorer Screenshot with hostconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DAej.png)

### Where it is not (but may be expected)

The subdirectories of `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data` are not exposed to WSL (for some reason):

```
deno@DeonJ-T570:/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data$ sudo ls -al
[sudo] password for deno: 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  40 May 25 12:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 May 25 12:09 ..
deno@DeonJ-T570:/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data$
```

Comment: You are right that all files can be found under the directory. But it's always rebuilt and my modification were all lost.

Comment: Do I just put that path into the explorer file search (after putting in the container id)?

Comment: Yes, `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\{containerid}` should take you straight to the hidden folder of the container.

Answer (score 11):

I know this question has already been answered, but the path in my system is different. In case anyone else has the same problem, I didn't want to keep the solution for myself.

The path to the Docker container on my system (Windows 11) is:

\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers

It's just slightly different, but until a few minutes ago, I doubted that the file hostconfig.json was accessible on my system because the numerous paths that you find on the internet didn't exist on my system.

Answer (score 5):

#### [Docker Desktop (Windows 10)](https://bestafiko.medium.com/docker-how-to-edit-bind-exist-container-ports-to-the-host-2ac15d97af0f)

You can find it here(see below steps for more info):

```
cd /var/lib/docker/containers/container-id
```

#### Steps to change container *host port*, without deleting the container:

- Stop running container
- *docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -it -v /:/host alpine*
- *chroot /host*
- *cd /var/lib/docker/containers/*container-id**
- *cat hostconfig.json* //You will see the current port that you are using
- *echo '*the above json, with the changed port*' > hostconfig.json* //Use outer single-quotes to preserve the json double-quotes
- Restart docker-desktop