# rabbitmq docker wss not working even though https works

Tags: docker, ssl, https, rabbitmq, ws

**Update**
I initially started the docker container using this command:

```sh
sudo docker run -d -it --hostname some-rabbitmq --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -p 15674:15674 --restart=unless-stopped -v /opt/rabbitmq-test:/etc/rabbitmq/ rabbitmq:3.9-management
```

However I needed to add tls without losing the info that was already saved on it, so I added more ports by stopping the docker container and service, updating the `config.v2.json` and `hostconfig.json` files to add the ports I wanted to expose, including `15673`.

---

I'm using the [official rabbitmq docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) as my rabbitmq server. I've configured tls but for some reason the `wss://` connection fails completely. This is my rabbitmq.conf file

```
loopback_users.guest = false
management.cors.allow_origins.1 = *
management.tcp.port = 80

# ===========================================================================
# ====================== TLS for webstomp plugin ============================
# ===========================================================================

# source of tls settings for webstomp plugin: https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html#tls-versions
web_stomp.ssl.port       = 15673
web_stomp.ssl.backlog    = 1024
web_stomp.ssl.cacertfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/chain.pem
web_stomp.ssl.certfile   = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/cert.pem
web_stomp.ssl.keyfile    = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/privkey.pem
# web_stomp.ssl.password   = changeme

web_stomp.ssl.honor_cipher_order   = true
web_stomp.ssl.honor_ecc_order      = true
web_stomp.ssl.client_renegotiation = false
web_stomp.ssl.secure_renegotiate   = true

web_stomp.ssl.versions.1 = tlsv1.2
web_stomp.ssl.versions.2 = tlsv1.1
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.1 = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.2 = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.3 = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.4 = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.5 = ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.6 = ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.7 = ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.8 = ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
web_stomp.ssl.ciphers.9 = DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

# ==========================================================================
# ====================== TLS for manangement ui ============================
# ==========================================================================

# source of tls settings for management ui: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#single-listener-https
management.ssl.port = 443
# management.ssl.cacertfile = /opt/rabbitmq-test/tls-ca/letsencrypt.pem
management.ssl.cacertfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/chain.pem
management.ssl.certfile   = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/cert.pem
management.ssl.keyfile    = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/privkey.pem
## This key must only be used if private key is password protected
# management.ssl.password   = bunnies

# For RabbitMQ 3.7.10 and later versions
management.ssl.honor_cipher_order   = true
management.ssl.honor_ecc_order      = true
management.ssl.client_renegotiation = false
management.ssl.secure_renegotiate   = true

management.ssl.versions.1 = tlsv1.2
management.ssl.versions.2 = tlsv1.1

management.ssl.ciphers.1 = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
management.ssl.ciphers.2 = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
management.ssl.ciphers.3 = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
management.ssl.ciphers.4 = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
management.ssl.ciphers.5 = ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
management.ssl.ciphers.6 = ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
management.ssl.ciphers.7 = ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
management.ssl.ciphers.8 = ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
management.ssl.ciphers.9 = DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
## Usually RabbitMQ nodes do not perform peer verification of HTTP API clients
## but it can be enabled if needed. Clients then will have to be configured with
## a certificate and private key pair.
##
## See https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#peer-verification for details.
# management.ssl.verify = verify_peer
# management.ssl.fail_if_no_peer_cert = true

# ==========================================================================
# ========================= TLS for core server ============================
# ==========================================================================

# source of tls settings: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#testssl-sh
listeners.ssl.default  = 5671
# ssl_options.cacertfile = /opt/rabbitmq-test/tls-ca/letsencrypt.pem
ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/chain.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = /etc/letsencrypt/live/{example.com}/privkey.pem
ssl_options.versions.1 = tlsv1.2
ssl_options.verify               = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false

ssl_options.honor_cipher_order   = true
ssl_options.honor_ecc_order      = true

# These are highly recommended for TLSv1.2 but cannot be used
# with TLSv1.3. If TLSv1.3 is enabled, these lines MUST be removed.
ssl_options.client_renegotiation = false
ssl_options.secure_renegotiate   = true

ssl_options.ciphers.1  = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl_options.ciphers.2  = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl_options.ciphers.3  = ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl_options.ciphers.4  = ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl_options.ciphers.5  = DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl_options.ciphers.6  = DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl_options.ciphers.7  = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ssl_options.ciphers.8  = ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ssl_options.ciphers.9  = ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ssl_options.ciphers.10 = ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ssl_options.ciphers.11 = DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ssl_options.ciphers.12 = DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

If you didn't read all that, the web_stomp plugin is configured to accept `wss://` connections on port `15673`, and regular `ws://` on `15674`. Note that I'm not using `amqp` and therefore `amqps` is not configured.

With this configuration I'm able to connect to `ws://example.com:15674/ws` using a webstomp javascript library using this code:

```js
    const stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
        brokerURL: url,
        connectHeaders: {
            login: userId,
            passcode: password,
        },
        reconnectDelay: 20000,
        heartbeatIncoming: 10000,
        heartbeatOutgoing: 10000,
      });
    // ... set my onConnect and onError listeners
     stompClient.activate();
```

I'm also able to access both `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` from the browser. But strangely I
cannot access `wss://example.com:15673/ws` using the same javascript code above.

When I run `sudo docker logs rabbitmq` (`rabbitmq` is the name of the running container), I see entries like this:

```
2022-02-08 16:06:45.314017+00:00 [info] <0.11704.33> accepting AMQP connection <0.11704.33> (162.142.125.221:54938 -> 172.17.0.2:5672)
2022-02-08 16:06:45.314245+00:00 [erro] <0.11704.33> closing AMQP connection <0.11704.33> (162.142.125.221:54938 -> 172.17.0.2:5672):
2022-02-08 16:06:45.314245+00:00 [erro] <0.11704.33> amqp1_0_plugin_not_enabled
2022-02-08 16:40:01.274168+00:00 [noti] <0.12580.33> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:346 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security
2022-02-08 16:40:01.274168+00:00 [noti] <0.12580.33>  - no_suitable_ciphers
2022-02-08 16:40:02.790021+00:00 [noti] <0.12597.33> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:346 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security
2022-02-08 16:40:02.790021+00:00 [noti] <0.12597.33>  - no_suitable_ciphers
2022-02-08 16:40:03.423216+00:00 [noti] <0.12604.33> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:346 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security
2022-02-08 16:40:03.423216+00:00 [noti] <0.12604.33>  - no_suitable_ciphers
2022-02-08 16:40:06.467195+00:00 [noti] <0.12610.33> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:346 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security
2022-02-08 16:40:06.467195+00:00 [noti] <0.12610.33>  - no_suitable_ciphers
2022-02-08 18:12:36.615274+00:00 [noti] <0.16116.33> TLS server: In state hello at tls_record.erl:564 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Unexpected Message
2022-02-08 18:12:36.615274+00:00 [noti] <0.16116.33>  - {unsupported_record_type,65}
2022-02-08 18:28:00.774093+00:00 [noti] <0.16535.33> TLS server: In state hello at tls_record.erl:564 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Unexpected Message
2022-02-08 18:28:00.774093+00:00 [noti] <0.16535.33>  - {unsupported_record_type,71}
```

None of these entries correspond to my actual attempts to connect. I don't know which connections are triggering these logs because my actual connection attempts do not show up in the logs.

RabbitMQ's website has a page for [troubleshooting ssl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html), but when I go into the docker container (using `docker exec -it rabbitmq bash`) and try to use the `rabbit-diagnostics` command, I get:

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@name-rabbitmq-test.localdomain'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.
```

I've also tried using the `openssl s_client` command mentioned in the troubleshooting page, but what I get is `Error: verify error:num=2:unable to get issuer certificate`. I've tried using both `chain.pem` and `fullchain.pem` (the CA files provided by letsencrypt) without any luck, it's the same error.

I'm not a rabbitmq expert so I'm not really sure how to proceed. I tried to include additional info about what I've tried, but please remember that the **main problem is that I cannot connect using `wss://` even though I can connect with `ws://` and `https://`**. Any ideas as to why this happening or what can help me resolve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you opened the necessary ports on the container?

Comment: @jhmckimm Yep I have. That's why I can access `https://` and `ws://`. And port `15673` is open too.

Comment: Is there a way to specifically check in case `15673` actually didn't get exposed somehow?

Comment: Can you update your question with the command you're using to run the container?

Comment: You could also run `docker inspect rabbitmq` and check out the ports configuration to verify.

Comment: Interesting. So from the `inspect` command I can see that `PortBindings` has the correct mappings for `15673` but `ExposedPorts` and `NetworkSettings.Ports` do not. That must be it right? I've updated the post with my starting command and I think I'll need to also need to updated `Exposed` ports in the `config.vs.json` file. Does that sound about right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ExposedPorts are the ones that come from the image and that you don't need to worry about those.

Comment: Adding `15673` to `ExposedPorts` did the trick! Thank you! :)

Comment: @jhmckimm please submit your suggesion as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to take the credit for this one, I merely pointed you in what I thought was the right direction. You are free to answer your own question with the details of what was wrong and how you fixed it, though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @jhmckimm for the idea. The problem was that port `15673` from the docker container was not exposed by the host. To fix this I had to add that port to the `ExposedPorts` in the `/var/lib/docker/containers/[hash_of_the_container]/config.v2.json` file of the docker system. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38783433/7987987) for more information.