# I lost my docker container when i change the hostconfig.json file

Tags: docker, containers

I want to assign new port mapping to my existing container,
so i changed the `/var/lib/docker/containers/{containerid}/hostconfig.json` and `config.v2.json` files.

But after changing, I lost my docker container...

The missing container does not appear through `docker ps -a` command.
But it still exists in `/var/lib/docker/containers`

(Plus)
I tried to start my lost container by container id, using `sudo docker start {container_id} command`.
But it also does not work.

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: e96f84691fff
```

What should I do?
Please help me

Comment: Do this help you to solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container/38783433#38783433

Comment: Hi PRATHEESH, actually I tried to change port mapping after seeing that answer on stack overflow. But it doesn't work for me. One suspicious thing is that the docker service didn't seem to shut down completely when I modified the config file.

Comment: You should `docker stop` and `docker rm` your existing container, and `docker run` a new one with the correct port mapping.  Never modify the files in `/var/lib/docker`.  A container is just a wrapper around a process and isn't especially valuable; think of this the same way as if you had started a program with the wrong command-line arguments.